# How do you change the name of the default export of a folder in React?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, configuration

Naturally in React you can alias importing `./component/<name>/index.js` as `./component/<name>`.

Is there a way in Webpack to change the name of the file that is used as the default? In this case, changing the `index.js` to a different file name?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript and by extension Webpack only allows `index.js` files as default when a directory is used. However, when using Webpack it is possible to write a plugin tapping into a hook for `before-existing-directory` and return the file you require as `index` at build time.

Luckily, this plugin is already written [`directory-named-webpack-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/directory-named-webpack-plugin).

```
  var DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin = require("directory-named-webpack-plugin");

  resolve: {
    plugins: [
      new DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin()
    ]
  }
```

If there is a folder named `foo`, this makes webpack look for `foo/foo.js` instead of the default `index` file. It also supports a custom `transform` function, so you can choose the file that gets selected, but I would strongly advise against that as it can get confusing real fast.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at this. What I'm trying to accomplish is utilizing Webpack to construct different versions of the same code base in the form of a limited functionality codebase for external use. RBI has an example in their talk [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKBDUhGi76o).

I'll look into using this to accomplish the same effect.

Comment: @ElijahPenney you can look at the code for plugin, should help you to implement this functionality

Comment: I'm getting an error:

`resolver.ensureHook is not a function`

Seems to be related to https://github.com/shaketbaby/directory-named-webpack-plugin/issues/28

But that marks it resolved by using the correct version (version 2) with webpack version 3. I'm using webpack v4 with the released version of the plugin. Any ideas?

Comment: @ElijahPenney Is it in collision with storybook as the issue describes?

Comment: No. I'm not using storybook. But there doesn't seem to be much more information on the matter that doesn't link back to that ticket.

Comment: Since it seems to be unrelated, I went ahead and created a new ticket for that plugin. [Issue #37](https://github.com/shaketbaby/directory-named-webpack-plugin/issues/37)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was just missing an object layer. I had:

```
plugins: [
    new DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin()
]
```

instead of:

```
resolve: {
    plugins: [
      new DirectoryNamedWebpackPlugin()
    ]
  }
```